# SQL Job error: The query processor could not produce a query plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

Running this SQL from a SQL Server Agent Job:

```
delete p
from sometable p
join sometable_deletes src on src.primarykeyid = p.primarykeyid
```

But I get this error:

> Error: 8624, Severity: 16, State: 116.
>   Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor could not produce a query plan. For more information, contact Customer Support Services.

The SQL runs fine directly in SQL Server Management Studio. Also, from a SQL Server Agent Job, I can run a similarly structured delete statement fine with different tables. But there is something wrong with this particular statement.

How can I figure out what the actual issue is here? Or get more error info?

Comment: Have a look at this article [`Troubleshooting : Error: 8624, Severity: 16, State: 21. Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor could not produce a query plan`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2014/07/15/troubleshooting-error-8624-severity-16-state-21-internal-query-processor-error-the-query-processor-could-not-produce-a-query-plan/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea why, but adding this to the top of the SQL in the SQL Server Agent Job resolved the issue for me:

```
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

Comment: This alone didn't work for me. I have no idea why but I had to add a GO after your line of code to make it work

Comment: It worked for me too, @pkr298. I also am not sure why yet. 

Thank you for posting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue and resolved it by restructure the query and replaced a full outer join with a left outer join - hope this helps!